# proof for Spivak's Calulus chapter 13 theorem 2

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

> Chapter 13 - Theorem 2: If $f$ is bounded on $[a,b]$, then $f$ is integrable if and only if for every $\epsilon>0$ such that there exists a partition $P$ where $U(f,P)-L(f,P)<\epsilon$.

Note: $U(f,P)$ and $L(f,P)$ denotes upper and lower sum.

I have trouble believing the proof of the forward direction.This is Spivak's proof:

> If $f$ is integrable, then $\textbf{L}\int_a^b fdx=\textbf{U}\int_a^b fdx$.
> ***Thus, there exist partitions*** $P'$ and $P''$ for $U(f,P'')-L(f,P')<\epsilon$.
> Let $P=P' \cup P''$ and we'll get the desired inequality (a consequence of an earlier lemma).

The part of the proof which I can't convince myself is in bold. I guess most readers and the writer finds it something trivial. It is obvious that such partitions exist or else the lower bound and upper bound won't be equal.

My attempt to justify it is as such. Is it a valid argument?

> $\forall \alpha, \beta >0$, there can always be a partition $P', P''$ such that $\textbf {L} \int_a^b f dx - L(f,P')\leq\alpha$ and $ U(f,P') - \textbf {U} \int_a^b f dx \leq\beta$ (by definition of least upper bound, and greatest lower bound). As such, $U(f,P'')-L(f,P')\leq \beta-\alpha <\epsilon$

Comment: It should be $\beta + \alpha$, but otherwise the reasoning is correct.

Comment: For the forward direction, by definition of (Darboux) integrability, your function is integrable if the upper and lower integrals are equal, and that is equivalent to the fact that both upper and lower sums can be made as close as we want to the value of the integral. If you choose a partition $P'$ such that the lower sum is within $\epsilon/2$ from the integral and a partition $P''$ such that the upper sum is within $\epsilon/2$ from the integral, you get what Spivak claims. Then you just take a common refinement.